# Jquery change background of elements with two parts of class

Tags: jquery, class

this is my code: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2orakwdx/)

I want to use this: `$('div[class*="test"]').css('background-color', 'green');`

It's working for every class that contains the string "test", now i want try to change background when the div contains "test" and "Div" (so my first three elements), i don't understand how to do this.
I want try to do something like: `$('div[class*="test" || "Div"]').css('background-color', 'green');`

Comment: $('div[class*="test"][class*="Div"]').css('background-color', 'green');  this is working, fine

Comment: `div[class=*test][class*=div]` is the equivalent of `&&` not `||` - do you want both or either?

Comment: You could use `$('div[class*="test"]:not(.test)').css('background-color', 'blue');` to select all classes that contain `test` but not `test` itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**AND jQuery**

```
$('div[class*="test"][class*="Div"]').css('background-color', 'green');
```

**OR jQuery**

```
$('div[class*="test"],div[class*="Div"]').css('background-color', 'green');
```

**NOR jQuery** test or Div but never both

```
$('div[class*="test"]:not([class*="Div"]),div[class*="Div"]:not([class*="test"])').css('background-color', 'green');
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not try like this?

```
$('[class*="Div"]:not([class="test"])').css('background-color', 'green');
```